# Using streams to collect to Map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following `TreeMap`:

```
TreeMap<Long,String> gasType = new TreeMap<>(); // Long, "Integer-Double"
gasType.put(1L, "7-1.50");
gasType.put(2L, "7-1.50");
gasType.put(3L, "7-3.00");
gasType.put(4L, "8-5.00");
gasType.put(5L, "8-7.00");
Map<Integer,TreeSet<Long>> capacities = new TreeMap<>);
```

The key is of the form `1L` (a `Long`), and value of the form `"7-1.50"` (a `String` concatenation of an `int` and a `double` separated by a `-`).

I need to create a new `TreeMap` where the keys are obtained by taking the `int` part of the values of the original `Map` (for example, for the value `"7-1.50"`, the new key will be `7`). The value of the new `Map` would be a `TreeSet` containing all the keys of the original `Map` matching the new key.

So, for the input above, the value for the `7` key will be the `Set` {1L,2L,3L}.

I can do this without `Stream`s, but I would like to do it with `Stream`s. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
Map<Integer,TreeSet<Long>> capacities = 
  gasType.entrySet()
         .stream ()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy (e -> Integer.parseInt(e.getValue().substring(0,e.getValue ().indexOf("-"))),
                                         TreeMap::new,
                                         Collectors.mapping (Map.Entry::getKey,
                                                             Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new))));
```

I modified the original code to support integers of multiple digits, since it appears you want that.

This produces the `Map`:

```
{7=[1, 2, 3], 8=[4, 5]}
```

If you don't care about the ordering of the resulting `Map` and `Set`s, you can let the JDK decide on the implementations, which would somewhat simplify the code:

```
Map<Integer,Set<Long>> capacities = 
  gasType.entrySet()
         .stream ()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy (e -> Integer.parseInt(e.getValue().substring(0,e.getValue ().indexOf("-"))),
                                         Collectors.mapping (Map.Entry::getKey,
                                                             Collectors.toSet())));
```

Comment: @Aominè see comment near the end that eliminates that assumption.

Comment: yup just about got to it :)

Comment: Yeah, Integers aren't always single digit and you have provided both possibilities.This is an elegant solution! Grateful to you! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You may try this out,

```
final Map<Integer, Set<Long>> map = gasType.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(entry -> Integer.parseInt(entry.getValue().substring(0, 1)),
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toSet())));
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to split the value based on "-" since there may be more that one digit, you can change it like so:

```
final Map<Integer, Set<Long>> map = gasType.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(entry -> Integer.parseInt(entry.getValue().split("-")[0]),
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toSet())));
```

Comment: Is there any way to split the value based on "-" so that other than single digit also can be utilized?

Comment: I have changed the answer according to your new requirement.

Comment: Thanks @Ravindra Sir.

Answer (score 2):

Other solution would be like this

```
list = gasType.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(m -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<Integer, Long>(Integer.valueOf(m.getValue().split("-")[0]), m.getKey()))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and second step:

```
list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
    Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new))));
```

or in one step:

```
gasType.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(m -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(Integer.valueOf(m.getValue().split("-")[0]), m.getKey()))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new))))
```

Comment: I will try this also, Thanks! much appreciated Sir.

Comment: Why do you need to map to SimpleEntry? That just adds further overhead which can be avoided and also collecting to a list only to create a stream from it in the middle of a stream pipeline is suboptimal. I’d do all the key extraction and value extraction in the groupingBy.

Comment: You are right, but i thought it shouldn't be same with other answer.`gasType.entrySet()
                .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m->Integer.valueOf(m.getValue().split("-")[0]),
                        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey,Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new))));`