# Convert a list of maps to a map of lists using Java Streams

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-stream

I would like to convert a list of maps to a map of lists. It is guaranteed that all the maps have the same keys.

For example, the following list

```json
[{key1: val1, key2: val2}, {key1: val3, key2: val4}]
```

gets converted to

```json
{key1: [val1, val3], key2: [val2, val4]}
```

The below code does it using for loops

```java
List<Map<String, Object>> data = getData();

Map<String, List<Object>> result = new HashMap<>();

for (Map<String, Object> element: data) {
    element.forEach((key, val) -> {
        if (result.containsKey(key))
            result.get(key).add(val);
        else
            result.put(key, Arrays.asList(val));
    });
}
```

How would I be able to achieve the same result using streams?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

E.g. like this, relying on the collect stage of java streams.

```java
List<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<>();

HashMap<String, List<Object>> transposed = data.stream()
        .flatMap(i -> i.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                HashMap::new,
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                        Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))));
```

There are a number of such application on SO (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50598185/using-streams-to-collect-to-map)), though not precisely tailored to this example.

Answer (score 5):

This version relying on [`stream.reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) should do it:

```java
// some values for testing
List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(Map.of("1", "One", "2", "Two"));
list.add(Map.of("3", "Three", "4", "Four", "5", "Five"));
list.add(Map.of("3", "Teen", "5", "Penta"));
list.add(Map.of("3", "Trice", "4", "Quattro"));

// conversion with stream reduction
Map<String, List<Object>> result = list.stream().reduce(new HashMap<>(),
        (acc, map) -> {
            map.forEach((k, v) -> acc.computeIfAbsent(k,
                    l -> new ArrayList<Object>()).add(v));
            return acc;
        },
        (acc1, acc2) -> {
            acc1.putAll(acc2);
            return acc1;
        });

// output
System.out.println(result);
//{1=[One], 2=[Two], 3=[Three, Teen, Trice], 4=[Four, Quattro], 5=[Five, Penta]}
```

**Explanation:** this code goes through each map in the list and accumulates it in the hashmap (1st parameter to the reduce function), with the accumulating function (2nd parameter) adding a new list to the hashmap if it sees a key for the first time (otherwise it accumulates in the list already present); the third function is required for consistency between running the stream function serially or in parallel (it combines partial results in parallel runs).

Answer (score 5):

You could do it without streams, yet in a modern fashion, as follows:

```
Map<String, List<Object>> result = new HashMap<>();
data.forEach(element -> 
    element.forEach((k, v) - > 
        result.computeIfAbsent(k, x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(v)));
```

This iterates the list and then each map and uses [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) to accomodate entries in the `result` map.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) method:

```java
List<Map<String, String>> listOfMaps = List.of(
        Map.of("key1", "val1", "key2", "val2"),
        Map.of("key1", "val3", "key2", "val4"));

Map<String, List<String>> mapOfLists = listOfMaps.stream()
        // Stream<Map<String,String>>
        .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
        // Stream<Map.Entry<String,String>>
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                // key
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                // value
                e -> List.of(e.getValue()),
                // merge function
                (list1, list2) -> {
                    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    list.addAll(list1);
                    list.addAll(list2);
                    return list;
                }, // map factory
                LinkedHashMap::new));

System.out.println(listOfMaps);
// [{key1=val1, key2=val2}, {key1=val3, key2=val4}]
System.out.println(mapOfLists);
// {key1=[val1, val3], key2=[val2, val4]}
```

---

<sup>See also: [Convert a map of lists into a list of maps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66700962/15495739)</sup>